# Issue with Google Charts API Line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

When I create a Google Charts Line Chart with one row, it doesn't show anything:

http://jsfiddle.net/bensinclair/zyMSd/2/ (excuse the messy code, the only way I could get it to work was to put the JavaScirpt in the HTML box)

But then with exactly the same code and adding another row to the chart, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/bensinclair/KnVQh/

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google line chart doesn't show a single datapoint unless you add a pointSize to show a round dot for the datapoint.